# Formatting a new array with existing data - problem

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a new array from the data object that I have which looks like this:

```
const data= {
  periods: [{
    month: 'January',
    types: [
      {
        name: 'sick leave',
        difference: '14',
        revisioned: '7000',
        paid: '5000',
      },
      {
        name: 'holiday',
        difference: '12',
        revisioned: '4000',
        paid: '6000',
      },
    ],
    received: '3000',
    taken: '2000',
    result: '0',
  },
  {
    month: 'February',
    types: [
      {
        name: 'sick leave',
        difference: '5',
        revisioned: '100',
        paid: '200',
      },
      {
        name: 'holiday',
        difference: '4',
        revisioned: '300',
        paid: '232',
      },
    ],
    received: '-2000',
    taken: '2000',
    result: '0',
  }],
};
```

What I would like to do is, to take that object and take the properties `types`, `received`, `taken` and `result` and from each of these properties values create an array that would be a property of an object in a new array. The end result of the new array would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'sick_leave_difference',
    result: ['14', '5'],
  },
  {
    name: 'sick_leave_revisioned',
    result: ['7000', '100'],
  },
  {
    name: 'sick_leave_paid',
    resultat: '[5000, 200]',
  },
  {
    name: 'holiday_difference',
    resultat: ['12', '4'],
  },
  {
    name: 'holiday_revisioned',
    result: ['4000', '300'],
  },
  {
    name: 'holiday_paid',
    result: '[6000, 232]',
  },
  {
    name: 'received',
    resultat: ['3000', '-2000'],
  },
  {
    navn: 'taken',
    result: ['2000', '2000'],
  },
  {
    name: 'result',
    result: ['0', '0'],
  },
];
```

The problem is that the propery types contains an array and it is different is different from the other properties, so I am not sure how to achieve this and also in an elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to extract and flatten the `types` array. Reduce the flattened array, and iterate the each object's [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Create the result object if it doesn't exists, and add the results. Extract back to array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const data= {"periods":[{"month":"January","types":[{"name":"sick leave","difference":"14","revisioned":"7000","paid":"5000"},{"name":"holiday","difference":"12","revisioned":"4000","paid":"6000"}],"received":"3000","taken":"2000","result":"0"},{"month":"February","types":[{"name":"sick leave","difference":"5","revisioned":"100","paid":"200"},{"name":"holiday","difference":"4","revisioned":"300","paid":"232"}],"received":"-2000","taken":"2000","result":"0"}]};

const result = Object.values(data.periods
  .reduce((r, { types }) => [...r, ...types], [])
  .reduce((r, { name, ...props }) => {
    Object.entries(props).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      const navn = `${name} ${k}`.replace(' ', '-');
      
      if(!r[navn]) r[navn] = { navn, result: [] };
      
      r[navn].result.push(v);
    });
    
    return r;
  }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the only problem I have now is that I get an error in React ```error  Assignment to property of function parameter 'r'  no-param-reassign```

Comment: Dori I still get the same error, even with the latest update.